# RewriteRule not working for files with known formats (.mp4, .mp3, .zip, .exe, and .pdf)

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

according to the [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24124416/301-redirect-mp4-file-to-a-link) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8416042/htaccess-redirect-all-pages-under-a-folder-to-new-domain):
I have this RewriteRules  in .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^download/(.*)$ http://dl-bio.ir/bio/$1 [L,R=301]
```

my directory `http://ex.com/download/` contains 5 sub-folder and 100 files with .mp4, .mp3, .zip, .exe, and .pdf format.

this RewriteRule dose not work for a file with known format. for the example,the RewriteRule does not work for the following links:

```
http://ex.com/download/bio/book.pdf
http://ex.com/download/ddd/m1.mp4
http://ex.com/download/ggg/book.pdf
http://ex.com/download/bio/book.zip
```

but RewriteRule works for the file with unusual formats. for the example,the RewriteRule does work correctly for the following links:

```
http://ex.com/download/bio/book.pdf55
http://ex.com/download/ddd/m1.mp4gh
http://ex.com/download/ggg/book.pdfgh
http://ex.com/download/bio/book.zipgh
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you copied and pasted your rewrite rule? Not to be stupid, but your rewrite rule (at least as you've posted it in the question) says 'downlod', and the links you are trying to match say 'download'. So you need to edit the question or edit the rule! ;)

Comment: a misspelled in the question. RewriteRule is not working yet.

Comment: There is no reason why this should treat different suffixes differently. Make sure that you are not getting fooled by already cached earlier results maybe, by deleting the browser history, or testing in a private tab. If that’s not it, do you have any other rewriting configured elsewhere? Do the files physically exist in the originally requested location maybe?